# Is the sunna pre-Fajr prayer before the Fajr adhan?

Tags: fiqh, fajr

From a hadith:

> Allah's Apostle used to offer eleven Rakat and that was his prayer. He used to prolong the prostration to such an extent that one could recite fifty verses (of the Quran) before he would lift his head. He used to pray two Rakat (Sunna) before the Fajr prayer and **then used to lie down on his right side till the call-maker came and informed him about the prayer.** (Bukhari, Book 21, 223)

I've always thought that the sunna prayer before Fajr was before the period when one could pray Fajr (i.e. before the adhan). But from the wording of the hadith it sounds like one would pray this sunna prayer in the late night and then wait for Fajr adhan.

Could someone clarify?

Answer (score 2):

The verse in question is specifically about the call of the Iqama, and not the adhan.

> Allah's Apostle offered the 'Isha' prayer (and then got up at the Tahajjud time) and offered eight Rakat and then offered two Rakat while sitting. **He then offered two Rakat in between the Adhan and Iqama** (of the Fajr prayer) and he never missed them. (Bukhari 256)
>
> After offering the Sunna of the Fajr prayer, the Prophet used to talk to me, if I happen to be awake; otherwise **he would lie down till the Iqama call was proclaimed** (for the Fajr prayer). (Bukhari 258)